# HandleError vs HandleErrorAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

`HandleErrorAttribute` is the class name but when we use it in MVC we only write [`HandleError`]. Is this by convention?

I create a custom action filter with class name "`MyActionFilterAttribute`" and I was able to use both "[`MyActionFilter`]" as well as "[`MyActionFilterAttribute`]".

Can anyone clarify the difference? Thanks,

D.

Comment: I think there will be no difference. It might be just conventions over configuration in MVC.So we need to specify class name with Attribute.It will automatically lookup for appropriate class

Answer (score 0):

> By convention, all attribute names end with Attribute. However, several languages that target the runtime, such as Visual Basic and C#, do not require you to specify the full name of an attribute. For example, if you want to initialize System.ObsoleteAttribute, you only need to reference it as Obsolete.

See [MSDN - Applying Attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfz783fz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)